# For loop displays previous value with next value

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm trying to understand why my for loop keeps showing previous values in every iteration.

```
for (String value : list)
{
    String[] separated = value.split("/");
    final String readTime = separated[0];
    final String userID = separated[1];
    db.collection("users").document(userID)
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    readHistoryFields.append("\nNolasīšanas laiks: ").append(readTime);
                    readHistoryFields.append("\nVārds: ").append(doc.get("Name"));
                    readHistoryFields.append("\nUzvārds: ").append(doc.get("Surname")).append("\n");
                    readHistory.add(readHistoryFields.toString());
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NFCReadHistory.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, readHistory);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I have a for loop like this. It needs to display listview with each value that is in inside List.

When displaying results, they show up like this.

```
Val1

Val1
Val2

Val1
Val2
Val3

...
```

As far as i know it should be like this

```
Val1

Val2

Val3

...
```

Is there something that im missing while generating listview inside for loop?

Comment: You do create several adapters though. You should cache it instead

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and attaching adapter object to listview in forloop.On every iteration "readHistory" is getting increased and then it's getting added to listview.

Solution: Create an adapter object outside the loop having a final list of items and then attach it with listview.

Comment: It keeps on showing empty List when outside of loop